# Dropzone doesn't initialize when I get it as <tiles:insertAttribute name="..." />

Tags: javascript, jsp, tiles, dropzone.js

I have got template.jsp as the main file, in which I included various tiles like `<tiles:insertAttribute name="uploadContainer" />`.

If I put my Dropzone (using the library of dropzonejs.com) into a .jsp which is loaded immediately, it does work. No Problems.

Now I want to put this Dropzone in a tile which is loaded later, by clicking - and the Dropzone does not work anymore, it's not even activated.

I wondered if it's a problem of dropzone.js, which is included in the template.jsp before the dropzone-Form even exists, but the problem is still the same, if I include dropzone.js in the tile.

It has to be a simple mistake, but I simply doesn't see it. ._.

**template.jsp:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/dropzone.js"/>"></script>
```

and

```
<div id="uploadBox">
  <div id="uploadContainer">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="uploadContainer" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**pages.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="welcome" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="uploadContainer" value="/fileUpload" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**fileUpload.jsp**

```
<div id="uploadContainer">
    <div class="innerContentBoxItem">

        <form:form method="POST" action="uploadFile" class="dropzone"
            id="my-awesome-dropzone" commandName="fileUploadForm"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="label" value="test" />
        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        //...
    };
</script>
```

Above you see the WORKING Version. The main difference of my intent now is, that I want to do this:

**pages.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="welcome" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="uploadContainer" value="" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

and load the new content (including the Dropzone) by clicking on an element.
Result is: the new content is loaded, but Dropzone remains inactive.

Any ideas?